# Correct Behaviour for Requesting Incorrect Scopes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

In regard to OpenID Connect and the MSAL library, what should the correct behaviour be if you request incorrect scopes, i.e. incorrectly spelt, or non-existent scopes?

We're testing this with Azure AD B2C and a React website using MSAL and when we try to acquire the token we simply get an empty result. Is this the correct behaviour or should we get an error?

Comment: Can you please provide code/configuration details that you have tried and the result details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case an invalid scope is requested an [Azure AD B2C error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes) (such as AADB2C90117 or AADB2C90205) should be thrown. Sometimes immediately after hitting the authorize endpoint while others after credentials have been submited.

Ensure [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging-js#configure-logging-in-msaljs) and [error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-js#error-handling-in-msaljs) are properly set up.